# How to custom my Navigation in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

OK, I choose [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) , so I write a demo

1. create a sample screen named PageScreen
2. create a TabNavigator

   ```
   export const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
       PageScreen: {screen: PageScreen, navigationOptions: { title: 'page1' }},
       PageScreen1: {screen: PageScreen, navigationOptions: { title: 'page2' }}
   })
   ```
3. this is the result:

   (result TabNavigator fill Horizontal)
4. my questions is :

   A: if my two screen links the same page , but I want to use a params to differentiate. for example if page1 ,PageScreen show page1 ,if page2 show page2. I don't find the method to pass param

   B: in some apps , navigation not fill Horizontal   [navigation is short not fill-x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnlYm.png)

How to modify navigation's style ?

Answer (score 1):

You should custom your navigation according to here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/custom

then you could have you own tab view style which fit your requirement

If you are looking for example you could check the official example code in github: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/CustomTabs.js